# IISRewrite encoding of %2f in path

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

So I have a path like this (I am using webforms): 
folder/first/second/ 
which has the following rewrite rule behind it

```
 <rule name="firstLevel">
                <match url="^folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="firstSecond.aspx?param1={R:1}&amp;param2={UrlEncode:{R:2}}" />
 </rule>
```

my issue is when I try and pass the following: 
folder/first/sec%2fond/ (I want R2 to be sec%2fond where I will urlDecode it back to the page. for a result like "sec/ond".

However my rule keeps taking it as though I want 
folder/first/sec/ond

Requested URL
   http://localhost:85/research/first/sec/ond/

Physical Path
   \rewritetest\folder\first\sec\ond\

Thanks for any assists..

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution to this issue for anyone else.

```
  <rule name="secondLevel">
      <match url="^folder/(.+)/(.+)/?$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="firstsecond.aspx?param1={C:1}&amp;param2={C:2}" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="/folder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
      </conditions>
  </rule>
```